# Why any data is shown when I execute this select in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, model

I'm trying to code into sql the following model I made: [image]

The code is divided into three parts. The creation of the Import tables where I insert the data by three csv files, the creation of the tables of the model, and the insertion of the data in each table using the imported data. As far as I am concerned, the model is rightly coded, but the relations might not be well coded, because when I execute a 'select * from ' I don't get any data. As if there where no info inserted. 
This is the code which I refer:

```
drop table if exists ImportA;
create table ImportA (

    id varchar(255),
    url varchar(255),
    name varchar(255),
    description text,
    picture_url varchar(255),
    street varchar(255),
    neighbourhood varchar(255),
    city varchar(255),
    state varchar(255),
    zipcode varchar(255),
    country_code varchar(255),
    country varchar(255),
    property_type varchar(255),
    accommodates varchar(255),
    bathrooms varchar(255),
    bedrooms varchar(255),
    beds varchar(255),
    amenities text,
    square_feet varchar(255),
    price varchar(255),
    weekly_price varchar(255),
    monthly_price varchar(255),
    security_deposit varchar(255),
    cleaning_fee varchar(255),
    minimum_nights varchar(255),
    maximum_nights varchar(255)
);

drop table if exists ImportH;
create table ImportH (

    url varchar(255),
    name varchar(255),
    description text,
    picture_url varchar(255),
    host_id  varchar(255),
    host_url varchar(255),
    host_name varchar(255),
    host_since varchar(255),
    host_about text,
    host_response_time varchar(255),
    host_response_rate varchar(255),
    host_is_superhost varchar(255),
    host_picture_url varchar(255),
    host_listings_count varchar(255),
    host_verifications varchar(255),
    host_identity_verified varchar(255)
);

drop table if exists ImportR;
create table ImportR (

    id varchar(255),
    url varchar(255),
    name varchar(255),
    description text,
    picture_url varchar(255),
    street varchar(255),
    neighbourhood varchar(255),
    city varchar(255),
    date_review varchar(255),
    reviewer_id varchar(255),
    reviewer_name varchar(255),
    comments text
);

copy ImportA from 'C:\BDD\apartments.csv' csv header delimiter ',';
copy ImportH from 'C:\BDD\hosts.csv' csv header delimiter ',';
copy ImportR from 'C:\BDD\review.csv' csv header delimiter ',';

drop table if exists Country cascade;
create table Country (

    country_code varchar(255),
    country varchar(255),
    primary key (country_code)
);

drop table if exists Payment cascade;
create table Payment (

    id_payment serial,
    price money,
    weekly_price money,
    monthly_price money,
    security_deposit money,
    cleaning_fee money,
    primary key (id_payment)
);

drop table if exists Characteristic cascade;
create table Characteristic (

    id_characteristic serial,
    property_type varchar(255),
    accommodates int,
    bathrooms int,
    bedrooms int,
    beds int,
    square_feet int,
    minimum_nights int,
    maximum_nights int,
    primary key (id_characteristic)
);

drop table if exists Host cascade;
create table Host (

    host_id serial,
    host_url varchar(255),
    host_name varchar(255),
    host_since date,
    host_about text,
    host_response_time varchar(255),
    host_response_rate varchar(255),
    host_is_superhost boolean,
    host_picture_url varchar(255),
    host_listings_count int,
    host_identity_verified boolean,
    primary key (host_id)
);

drop table if exists Media cascade;
create table Media (

    id_verification serial,
    media varchar(255),
    primary key (id_verification)
);

drop table if exists RelationHostMedia cascade;
create table RelationHostMedia (

    host_id int,
    id_verification int,
    primary key (host_id, id_verification),
    foreign key (host_id) references Host (host_id),
    foreign key (id_verification) references Media (id_verification)
);

drop table if exists Amenitie cascade;
create table Amenitie (

    id_amenitie serial,
    id_characteristic int,
    amenitie varchar(255),
    primary key (id_amenitie),
    foreign key (id_characteristic) references Characteristic (id_characteristic)
);

drop table if exists Place cascade;
create table Place (

    id_place serial,
    street varchar(255),
    neighbourhood varchar(255),
    city varchar(255),
    state varchar(255),
    zipcode varchar(255),
    country_code varchar(255),
    primary key (id_place),
    foreign key (country_code) references Country (country_code)
);

drop table if exists Apartment cascade;
create table Apartment (

    id_apartment serial,
    url varchar(255),
    name varchar(255),
    description text,
    picture_url varchar(255),
    id_place int,
    id_payment int,
    id_characteristic int,
    host_id int,
    primary key (id_apartment),
    foreign key (id_place) references Place (id_place),
    foreign key (id_payment) references Payment (id_payment),
    foreign key (id_characteristic) references Characteristic (id_characteristic),
    foreign key (host_id) references Host (host_id)
);

drop table if exists Reviewer cascade;
create table Reviewer (

    id_reviewer serial,
    reviewer_name varchar(255),
    primary key (id_reviewer)
);

drop table if exists Review cascade;
create table Review (

    id_review serial,
    id_reviewer int,
    id_apartment int,
    date_review date,
    comments text,
    primary key (id_review),
    foreign key (id_reviewer) references Reviewer (id_reviewer),
    foreign key (id_apartment) references Apartment (id_apartment)
);

insert into Country (country_code, country)
select distinct country_code, country
from ImportA;

insert into Payment (price, weekly_price, monthly_price, security_deposit, cleaning_fee)
select cast(price as money), cast(weekly_price as money), cast(monthly_price as money), cast(security_deposit as money), cast(cleaning_fee as money)
from ImportA;

insert into Characteristic (property_type, accommodates, bathrooms, bedrooms, beds, square_feet, minimum_nights, maximum_nights)
select property_type, cast(accommodates as int), cast(bathrooms as int), cast(bedrooms as int), cast(beds as int), cast(square_feet as int), cast(minimum_nights as int), cast(maximum_nights as int)
from ImportA;

insert into Host (host_id, host_url, host_name, host_since, host_about, host_response_time, host_response_rate, host_is_superhost, host_picture_url, host_listings_count, host_identity_verified)
select distinct cast(host_id as int), host_url, host_name, cast(host_since as date), cast(host_about as text), host_response_time, host_response_rate, cast(host_is_superhost as boolean), host_picture_url, cast(host_listings_count as int), cast(host_identity_verified as boolean)
from ImportH;

insert into Media (media)
select host_verifications
from ImportH;

insert into RelationHostMedia (host_id, id_verification)
select distinct host_id, id_verification
from Host, Media;

insert into Amenitie (id_characteristic, amenitie)
select id_characteristic, amenities
from Characteristic, ImportA;

insert into Place (street, neighbourhood, city, state, zipcode, country_code)
select street, neighbourhood, city, state, zipcode, country_code
from ImportA, Country;

insert into Reviewer (reviewer_name)
select reviewer_name
from ImportR;

insert into Apartment (id_apartment, url, name, description, picture_url, id_place, id_payment, id_characteristic, host_id)
select cast(id_apartment as int), url, name, cast(description as text), picture_url, id_place, id_payment, id_characteristic, host_id
from ImportA, Place, Payment, Characteristic, Host;

insert into Review (id_reviewer, id_apartment, date_review, comments)
select id_reviewer, id_apartment, cast(date_review as date), comments
from Reviewer, Apartment, ImportR;

select * from Place;
```

I'm using PostgreSQL in case anyone is wondering.

What's wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do the import tables have data?  If you were to do all of this in a single transaction, it would be easy to see if there were errors in the middle.

Comment: Yes, the data is correctly copied into the import tables.

Comment: you are missing all joins

Answer (score 2):

Based on your script, whether or not data exists in `Place` at the end depends on a whole slew of *other* things working correctly such as the first table copy from the `C:\BDD\apartments.csv` file. Either the import files are empty or an error is being thrown that you're not seeing.

To troubleshoot where the error is occurring, I would first confirm that the root source tables (ImportA, ImportH, ImportR) contain records after the script runs.

Assuming they have records, I suggest copying and pasting the script *one statement at a time* into your SQL client and executing. Keep going until you find the first error.
Fix it and continue running one statement at a time until you've proven that no statement produces an error.